# Enviar Paramêtros de Senha para execução de um comando Via Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh

Estou com um projeto que copia um arquivo de um servidor e o joga em um diretório mapeado para fazer a coleta de informações do arquivo , porém ao conectar e executar o comando para copiar , retorna o seguinte erro ->

> ([], ['Permission denied, please try again.\r\n', 'Permission denied, please try again.\r\n', 'Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).\r\n'])

Procurei mais afundo na internet e percebi que esse comando necessita de uma senha , porém eu não consigo colocar essa senha , eu já tentei o seguinte código

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.ssh.exec_command("scp root@p1:/home/pos/log/arqEspelho /retaguarda/", get_pty=True)
stdin.write('xxxxxx' + '\n')
```

porém não retorna nenhum erro e nenhuma maneira de eu colocar a senha , meu código está assim , alguma sugestão ?

```
import paramiko
from paramiko import SSHClient


class SSH:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.ssh = SSHClient()
            self.ssh.load_system_host_keys()
            self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            self.ssh.connect(hostname='172.20.0.1', port='22', username='root', password='root')

        except:
            print('Usuario ou senha Invalido')

    def exec_cmd(self, cmd):
        stdin, stdout, stderr = self.ssh.exec_command(cmd)
        if stderr.channel.recv_exit_status() != 0:
            print(stderr.read())
        else:
            print(stdout.read())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ssh = SSH()
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.ssh.exec_command("scp root@estacao1:/home/pos/log/arqEspelho /retaguarda/")
    retorno = stdout.readlines(), stderr.readlines()
    print(retorno)
```

Comment: Olá, seu código foi formatado para uma melhor aparência. Caso queira, é possível editar a postagem. Para isso basta clicar no botão [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/499153/edit). Também removi mensagens de cumprimentos [saiba o motivo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/38/como-se-portar-ao-perguntar-responder).